# How do I increase the row height of Google Timelines Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[image]

I've been working with Google Timeline Charts for a project. As you can see the full text of the event is not displayed. How do I increase the height of rows so that it displays the full text instead?

Comment: With css maybe?...

Comment: Check out the Google Charts API, there isn't any CSS to edit.

Comment: On your website there is...

Comment: Yeah I mean, you can't access the CSS of the charts (at least in any straightforward way).

Answer (score 3):

Was looking for the same thing.  Found a workaround... Changing the bar label's font size can be used to change the height of the bar itself.  It's crude, but it works!

```
timeline: {
    barLabelStyle: {
        fontSize: 50
    }
}
```

Credit goes to
https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-visualization-api/IKm5IlMx9es

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom your chart by setting greater value of width

```
var options = {
    width : 2000,
    ...
};
```

About CSS (comments). After chart.draw() there is SVG object contains chart. You can select elements like `svg > g:nth-child(5) > rect` and change properties.